# What is the S set of the ordered pairs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Two identical sets are given. A criterion is provided[given sets and link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfkAK.png) to create a proper relation with S.

These are the only correct combination for an integer. Thanks for your help in advance!

[my incorrect answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35vTM.png)

Comment: @coffeemath just fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a few, like $(1,-1),(-1,1),(2,-2),(-2,2).$ [no pairs other than what you have use the elements $\pm 3.$]

Comment: I had just figured it out right when you posted. Thanks alot

Comment: Good that you got it. [I don't think there's more...] welcome to the site.